# How to ensure a class derives only from predefined set of derived classes?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, inheritance

I am not even sure if this can be done. However, this is the situation at hand.

**I have a base class:**

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void fun();
private:
    int variable;
}
```

**Consider that I have two derived classes:**

```
class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void fun() override;
    virtual void moreFun();
private:
    int variable;
}
```

and

```
class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void fun() override;
    virtual void moreFun();
private:
    int variable;
}
```

I want to write a class ***Derived3*** which can be derived either from ***Derived1*** or ***Derived2***.

The idea is to have ***Derived3*** extend certain functionalities on top of one of the other derived classes. I don't intend to switch the class in runtime, but would like to initialize in a way similar to templates.

```
Template <class T>
class Derived3 : public T {
public:
    virtual void moreFun() override;
private:
    int variable;
}
```

Is it possible to ensure that the class Derived3 can be derived only from **Derived1** or **Derived2**?

Comment: In what way is the template solution not working for you?

Comment: The derived classes were just for an example. They have a lot of virtual functions that perform different tasks.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of an XY problem. Some more details about what doesn't work should be nice. It sounds like encapsulation or dependency injection (perhaps via templates) would work, but I cannot say without more information.

Comment: @AravindEV - downvoter's point is that, if some class can optionally  be derived from both bases, then ALL code which uses that derived class will only compile if it uses member function that are shared by both bases.   Call any member function that of `Derived1` that is not a member function of `Derived2` and the code won't compile at all.

Comment: It might not be the best idea to do so… as it can make the code hard to maintain if you more that the above 4 classes that are related. It might be preferable to use aggregation instead. **Reading good books** on design, on patterns and anti-patterns might be a good idea too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) will get you what you need. Just add it to the classes body, and don't forget the include-file:

```
#include <type_traits>

    ...
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>(), "T in Derived3<T> must inherit from Base");
    ...
```

If you only want to allow specific derived classes instead of all of them, or want to disallow `Base` itself, look at [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).